# How to filter rows in a sf objects with a sample point

Tags: r, r-sf

I want to

```r
library(sf)
library(sp)

data(meuse)
meuse_sf <- st_as_sf(meuse, coords = c("x", "y"), crs = 28992)
#  I want to extract one point geometry such as meuse_sf[1,], and then join the meuse_sf
## I tried the code below, but it does not work
st_geometry(meuse_sf)[1]
temp <- st_as_sf(st_geometry(meuse_sf)[1])
meuse_sf[st_equals(meuse_sf, temp), ]
```

Therefore, I was confused by extract a point geometry in one sf object, then filter it in another sf object; in another case, when I get a location of a point which already known, and filter it in a sf object like below

```r
location_point <- st_point(c(181027, 333363))
# then how to filter the location_point in meuse_sf (get a sf feature)
```

Finally, I hope if there were some blogs or articles for me to practice and learn and compare the sf with arcgis, thanks so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't get completely the question, you can do `meuse_sf[1, ]` to get the geometry and the attributes of `meuse_sf` and `meuse_sf[meuse_sf[1,],]` to get the intersection. With `sf` there are three levels of objects:

- `sfg`: just a geometry
- `sfc`: a `sfg` with a coordinate reference system (spatial geometry)
- `sf`: a `sfc` with attributes (a data frame with a special column that has the geometry). Back to `sfc` with `st_geometry()`

See several examples:

```r
library(sf)
#> Warning: package 'sf' was built under R version 4.1.3
#> Linking to GEOS 3.10.2, GDAL 3.4.1, PROJ 7.2.1; sf_use_s2() is TRUE
library(sp)

data(meuse)
meuse_sf <- st_as_sf(meuse, coords = c("x", "y"), crs = 28992)

# One point
one_point <-  meuse_sf[1,]
class(one_point)
#> [1] "sf"         "data.frame"

one_point
#> Simple feature collection with 1 feature and 12 fields
#> Geometry type: POINT
#> Dimension:     XY
#> Bounding box:  xmin: 181072 ymin: 333611 xmax: 181072 ymax: 333611
#> Projected CRS: Amersfoort / RD New
#>   cadmium copper lead zinc  elev       dist   om ffreq soil lime landuse dist.m
#> 1    11.7     85  299 1022 7.909 0.00135803 13.6     1    1    1      Ah     50
#>                geometry
#> 1 POINT (181072 333611)

# The geom
one_point_geom <-  st_geometry(one_point)
class(one_point_geom)
#> [1] "sfc_POINT" "sfc"

one_point_geom
#> Geometry set for 1 feature 
#> Geometry type: POINT
#> Dimension:     XY
#> Bounding box:  xmin: 181072 ymin: 333611 xmax: 181072 ymax: 333611
#> Projected CRS: Amersfoort / RD New
#> POINT (181072 333611)

# Intersection
meuse_sf[one_point_geom, ]
#> Simple feature collection with 1 feature and 12 fields
#> Geometry type: POINT
#> Dimension:     XY
#> Bounding box:  xmin: 181072 ymin: 333611 xmax: 181072 ymax: 333611
#> Projected CRS: Amersfoort / RD New
#>   cadmium copper lead zinc  elev       dist   om ffreq soil lime landuse dist.m
#> 1    11.7     85  299 1022 7.909 0.00135803 13.6     1    1    1      Ah     50
#>                geometry
#> 1 POINT (181072 333611)


# Same as
st_filter(meuse_sf, one_point_geom)
#> Simple feature collection with 1 feature and 12 fields
#> Geometry type: POINT
#> Dimension:     XY
#> Bounding box:  xmin: 181072 ymin: 333611 xmax: 181072 ymax: 333611
#> Projected CRS: Amersfoort / RD New
#>   cadmium copper lead zinc  elev       dist   om ffreq soil lime landuse dist.m
#> 1    11.7     85  299 1022 7.909 0.00135803 13.6     1    1    1      Ah     50
#>                geometry
#> 1 POINT (181072 333611)

# With a point
location_point <- st_point(c(181027, 333363))
class(location_point)
#> [1] "XY"    "POINT" "sfg"

location_point
#> POINT (181027 333363)

# Need sfc class, that add crs information
location_point_sfc <- st_sfc(location_point, crs=st_crs(meuse_sf))

location_point_sfc
#> Geometry set for 1 feature 
#> Geometry type: POINT
#> Dimension:     XY
#> Bounding box:  xmin: 181027 ymin: 333363 xmax: 181027 ymax: 333363
#> Projected CRS: Amersfoort / RD New
#> POINT (181027 333363)

# Intersection
meuse_sf[location_point_sfc, ]
#> Simple feature collection with 1 feature and 12 fields
#> Geometry type: POINT
#> Dimension:     XY
#> Bounding box:  xmin: 181027 ymin: 333363 xmax: 181027 ymax: 333363
#> Projected CRS: Amersfoort / RD New
#>   cadmium copper lead zinc elev      dist  om ffreq soil lime landuse dist.m
#> 8     2.8     29  150  406 8.49 0.0921516 9.5     1    1    0      Ab    120
#>                geometry
#> 8 POINT (181027 333363)


# Same as
st_filter(meuse_sf, location_point_sfc)
#> Simple feature collection with 1 feature and 12 fields
#> Geometry type: POINT
#> Dimension:     XY
#> Bounding box:  xmin: 181027 ymin: 333363 xmax: 181027 ymax: 333363
#> Projected CRS: Amersfoort / RD New
#>   cadmium copper lead zinc elev      dist  om ffreq soil lime landuse dist.m
#> 8     2.8     29  150  406 8.49 0.0921516 9.5     1    1    0      Ab    120
#>                geometry
#> 8 POINT (181027 333363)
```

<sup>Created on 2023-03-28 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thanks for your comprehensive answer, you just understood my question and solved them.

Comment: Furthermore, I still have doubt on the `sgbp` object which generated by the series `geos_binary_pred` founction such as st_equals, how to understand the `sgbp` object and combine them with other sf objects or functions. In my view, the sgbp object was a list(not sure and found it may not suit the list operation), when I use st_equals to filter one sf object with duplicate geometry, it produce the results, and I found it hard to trace back to the origin sf object just like what I write in the question, would you explain it more?

Comment: Please open a new question, and provide some code. In this question there is not `sgbp` object

Comment: I opened a new question below, please check if you are convenient : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75883737/get-a-flattern-dataframe-from-sgbp-object-generated-by-geos-binary-pred-sf-f