# How to get a flattern (data)frame from sgbp object generated by geos_binary_pred {sf} function such as st_equals

Tags: r, r-sf

I tried to get the results where shows below

```r
library(sf)
#> Linking to GEOS 3.9.3, GDAL 3.5.2, PROJ 8.2.1; sf_use_s2() is TRUE
p1 = st_point(0:1)
p2 = st_point(2:1)
p3 = st_point(3:4) 
sitesvalue <- c(rnorm(9,mean=60,sd=10))
p = st_sf(a = letters[1:9],value = sitesvalue, geom = st_sfc(p1, p1, p2, p1, p1, p2, p2, p1, p3))

# 1. all the samples found in st_equals: geom(2,1), geom(0,1) and sorted by geom
# 
#  a       value        geom
#  a 45.44428429 POINT (0 1)
#  b 50.77745726 POINT (0 1)
#  d 54.19844325 POINT (0 1)
#  e 55.71605842 POINT (0 1)
#  h 55.84170275 POINT (0 1)
#  c 55.41422869 POINT (2 1) 
#  f 51.20012648 POINT (2 1)
#  g 54.98118876 POINT (2 1)
# 
# 
# 2. select some of samples: geom(2,1)
# 
#  a       value        geom
#  c 55.41422869 POINT (2 1) 
#  f 51.20012648 POINT (2 1)
#  g 54.98118876 POINT (2 1)
```

1. I tried to use `st_equals` and `st_intersects` function, they generate the `matrix` or `sgbp` class object and get the index, but I found it hard to operate them with what I desire to get, how it solved?

```
eq_mat <- st_equals(p, sparse = FALSE)
class(eq_mat)
#> [1] "matrix" "array"
eq_mat
#>        [,1]  [,2]  [,3]  [,4]  [,5]  [,6]  [,7]  [,8]  [,9]
#>  [1,]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
#>  [2,]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
#>  [3,] FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
#>  [4,]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
#>  [5,]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
#>  [6,] FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
#>  [7,] FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
#>  [8,]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
#>  [9,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE

eq_sgbp <- st_equals(p, sparse = TRUE)
### or st_intersects(p, remove_self = TRUE) will get the same results
class(eq_sgbp)
#> [1] "sgbp" "list"
eq_sgbp
#> Sparse geometry binary predicate list of length 9, where the predicate
#> was `equals'
#>  1: 1, 2, 4, 5, 8
#>  2: 1, 2, 4, 5, 8
#>  3: 3, 6, 7
#>  4: 1, 2, 4, 5, 8
#>  5: 1, 2, 4, 5, 8
#>  6: 3, 6, 7
#>  7: 3, 6, 7
#>  8: 1, 2, 4, 5, 8
#>  9: 9
```

2. furthermore, use st_intersection I GET A wide vector in cloumn origins but still can not compare each properties value in each duplicated sites, could it be solved?

```
st_intersection(p, remove_self = TRUE)
#> Simple feature collection with 3 features and 4 fields
#> Geometry type: POINT
#> Dimension:     XY
#> Bounding box:  xmin: 0 ymin: 1 xmax: 3 ymax: 4
#> CRS:           NA
#>   a    value n.overlaps       origins        geom
#> 3 c 54.03767          3       3, 6, 7 POINT (2 1)
#> 1 a 58.54622          5 1, 2, 4, 5, 8 POINT (0 1)
#> 9 i 59.55194          1             9 POINT (3 4)
```

3. and I also tried the code below, it doesn't work and how to check it?

```
p1 <- st_sfc(p1)
st_join(p1, p, join = st_equals)
#> Error in UseMethod("st_filter"): no applicable method for 'st_filter' applied to an object of class "c('sfc_POINT', 'sfc')"
```

<sup>Created on 2023-03-30 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

What is exactly the question? Based on

> ### and what I want is samples below
>
> #### all the samples found in st_equals: geom(2,1), geom(0,1) and sorted by geom
>
> ```r
> a        geom
> a POINT (0 1)
> b POINT (0 1)
> d POINT (0 1)
> e POINT (0 1)
> h POINT (0 1)
> c POINT (2 1)
> f POINT (2 1)
> g POINT (2 1)
> ```

It seems that you just want to sort the `sf` object by geometry. You can achieve this in a couple of ways with just base `sf`:

1. Transform the geometry to text (WKT) and sort by text string
2. Transform the geometry to numeric coordinates and sort by coordinates

```r
library(sf)
#> Warning: package 'sf' was built under R version 4.1.3
#> Linking to GEOS 3.10.2, GDAL 3.4.1, PROJ 7.2.1; sf_use_s2() is TRUE
p1 = st_point(0:1)
p2 = st_point(2:1)
p = st_sf(a = letters[1:8], geom = st_sfc(p1, p1, p2, p1, p1, p2, p2, p1))

p
#> Simple feature collection with 8 features and 1 field
#> Geometry type: POINT
#> Dimension:     XY
#> Bounding box:  xmin: 0 ymin: 1 xmax: 2 ymax: 1
#> CRS:           NA
#>   a        geom
#> 1 a POINT (0 1)
#> 2 b POINT (0 1)
#> 3 c POINT (2 1)
#> 4 d POINT (0 1)
#> 5 e POINT (0 1)
#> 6 f POINT (2 1)
#> 7 g POINT (2 1)
#> 8 h POINT (0 1)

# Get geom as text
st_as_text(p$geom)
#> [1] "POINT (0 1)" "POINT (0 1)" "POINT (2 1)" "POINT (0 1)" "POINT (0 1)"
#> [6] "POINT (2 1)" "POINT (2 1)" "POINT (0 1)"

# Order
p[order(st_as_text(p$geom)), ]
#> Simple feature collection with 8 features and 1 field
#> Geometry type: POINT
#> Dimension:     XY
#> Bounding box:  xmin: 0 ymin: 1 xmax: 2 ymax: 1
#> CRS:           NA
#>   a        geom
#> 1 a POINT (0 1)
#> 2 b POINT (0 1)
#> 4 d POINT (0 1)
#> 5 e POINT (0 1)
#> 8 h POINT (0 1)
#> 3 c POINT (2 1)
#> 6 f POINT (2 1)
#> 7 g POINT (2 1)

# Another approach based on coords

df_coors <- st_coordinates(p)

df_coors
#>   X Y
#> 1 0 1
#> 2 0 1
#> 3 2 1
#> 4 0 1
#> 5 0 1
#> 6 2 1
#> 7 2 1
#> 8 0 1

order(df_coors[,1], df_coors[,2])
#> [1] 1 2 4 5 8 3 6 7


# And again
p[order(df_coors[,1], df_coors[,2]), ]
#> Simple feature collection with 8 features and 1 field
#> Geometry type: POINT
#> Dimension:     XY
#> Bounding box:  xmin: 0 ymin: 1 xmax: 2 ymax: 1
#> CRS:           NA
#>   a        geom
#> 1 a POINT (0 1)
#> 2 b POINT (0 1)
#> 4 d POINT (0 1)
#> 5 e POINT (0 1)
#> 8 h POINT (0 1)
#> 3 c POINT (2 1)
#> 6 f POINT (2 1)
#> 7 g POINT (2 1)
```

<sup>Created on 2023-03-30 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: I am sorry to bother you and hope the rewrite content will be clear. Sorting the results is good, and I have doubts on the `sgbp` and `matrix` object produced by `st_equals` etc, and I tried several codes and found something compatible, waiting for your kind and general answer.